# Add custom knockout component to checkout sidebar in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout, uicomponent, knockoutjs

I'd like to know what is the best approach to add a custom knockout component to the checkout sidebar in Magento 2, an example assuming we already have a custom module would be great

[image: example]

UPDATE:

As I needed a placeholder different than the "summary", I followed Sohel's answer and also did those steps

Override sidebar template in module's requirejs-config.js:

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'Magento_Checkout/template/sidebar.html': 'SR_MagentoCommunity/template/sidebar.html',
            sidebar: 'SR_MagentoCommunity/js/sidebar'
        }
    }
};
```

Add a new region called "timer" in the new overriden sidebar.html template:

```
<div id="opc-sidebar"
     data-bind="afterRender:setModalElement, mageInit: {
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal':{
        'type': 'custom',
        'modalClass': 'opc-sidebar opc-summary-wrapper',
        'wrapperClass': 'checkout-container',
        'parentModalClass': '_has-modal-custom',
        'responsive': true,
        'responsiveClass': 'custom-slide',
        'overlayClass': 'modal-custom-overlay',
        'buttons': []
    }}">

    <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('summary') -->
        <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
    <!--/ko-->

    <div class="opc-block-shipping-information">
        <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('shipping-information') -->
            <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
        <!--/ko-->
    </div>

    <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('timer') -->
        <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
    <!--/ko-->

</div>
```

Update checkout_index_index.xml to place the component in the new region:

```
<item name="sidebar" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">

        <item name="timer" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string"> SR_MagentoCommunity/js/timer</item>
            <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">timer</item>
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="template" xsi:type="string"> SR_MagentoCommunity/timer</item>
            </item>
        </item>

    </item>
</item>
```

And this is the final result:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the following way:

***Step 1:*** *app/code/SR/MagentoCommunity/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="sidebar" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="custom_sidebar" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">SR_MagentoCommunity/js/view/custom_sidebar</item>
                                            <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">summary</item>
                                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">SR_MagentoCommunity/custom_sidebar</item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

***Step 2:*** *app/code/SR/MagentoCommunity/view/frontend/web/js/view/custom_sidebar.js*

```
define([
    'uiComponent',
    'ko',
    'jquery'
], function (Component, ko, $,) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({

    });
});
```

***Step 3:*** *app/code/SR/MagentoCommunity/view/frontend/web/template/custom_sidebar.html*

```
<h1>Custom Sidebar</h1>
```

Clear cache, delete static content.

***Note:*** SR_MagentoCommunity is module name