# Please help me to add a block in the red area like on the image. Thank you

Tags: magento2

[image]

Help me to add a cms block in the red area like above image (after sidebar) by checkout / index / index. Thank you for your help

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/319269/add-custom-knockout-component-to-checkout-sidebar-in-magento-2

Comment: Thanks for the answer https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/4329/sohel-rana

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using Theme :-**
`app/design/frontend/Theme/ThemeName/Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml` file

```
<referenceContainer name="checkout.cart.container">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="checkout.cart.content.block" after="-" template="Magento_Checkout::custom.phtml"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

**Using Custom module :-**

create `app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
       <referenceContainer name="checkout.cart.container">
          <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="checkout.cart.content.block" after="-" template="Magento_Checkout::custom.phtml"/>
       </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer